# conversion of string to stringbuilder object so that reverse option can be applied to string

Tags: java

Basically, I am converting decimal to binary for which I have defined a method `conversionBinaryDecimal()`, in which I am passing an integer n to it and each time I divide n by 2 and add remainder to string variable inBinary by  concatenation. 
But when I am adding remainder it's getting stored in opposite order. For example: 6 binary is 110 but it is stored as 011. So, I want to reverse the String to get exact answer. For this I am using StringBuilder to convert it to mutable string but When I am using reverse inbuilt method to it. It says configure Assignment.

I have tried search everywhere to get the why it is so? but I am not getting it.

```
package conversionbinarydecimal;
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConversionBinaryDecimal {
    static void decimalToBinary(int n){
        String inBinary = "";
        while(n>0){
            int temp = (n%2);
            inBinary += temp;
            n=n/2;
        }
        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder(); 
        input1.append(inBinary); 
        input1 = input1.reverse(); 
        System.out.println(inBinary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        decimalToBinary(n);

    }

}
```

I am getting compiler error.
The expected output is Binary of any number. For example: 6: 110

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you get a compiler error, please *always* include the error itself in the question, including where it is. I *suspect* the problem is in `input1 = input1.reverse();` because the return type of `StringBuilder.reverse()` is `AbstractStringBuilder`. You can just call `input1.reverse()` and ignore the return value because its reverse in place.

Comment: You should be printing 'input1' not 'inBinary' !

Comment: There seems no CompileTimeError with your code.

Comment: @RaghavAnand Are you *sure* you get a compilation error?

Comment: You should use a StringBuilder rather than concatenating strings in a loop. String concatenation creates a new string object each time and discards it in the next iteration, whereas using a StringBuilder keeps the same object most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing out the `input1` String, instead you are printing out `inBinary`

Change your code as follows:

```
input1 = input1.reverse();
System.out.println(input1);
```

Comment: by mistake inBinary is there....even if I print input1 same error is there. I tried different things ..so I for got change inBinary to input1

Comment: I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Print correct variable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static void decimalToBinary(int n){
        String inBinary = "";
        while(n>0){
            int temp = (n%2);
            inBinary += temp;
            n=n/2;
        }
        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder(); 
        input1.append(inBinary); 
        input1 = input1.reverse(); 
        System.out.println(input1);// ISSUE was this line
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        decimalToBinary(6);
    }
}
```

If its not an interview question then why not use predefined method instead coding too much :)

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(6));
```